# Get a Sorted List by user

Tags: java

I need to get a list sorted by decreasing values of expenses, but by Taxpayer. Imagining the Taxpayer with number 1 has 3 expenses and the Taxpayer with number 2 has 2 expenses, I need to get the expenses from the first Taxpayer and sort them, then sort the expenses of Taxpayer number 2. What I had so far was:

```
 public TreeSet<Expense> getListFactIndivValor(){
   TreeSet<Expense> t = new TreeSet<Expense>(new ComparatorValue(-1)); //-1 because I had to use this comparator to do ascending order on another method
   Company c = (Company) this.users.get(userId); //Entity that issues expenses. has the method getExpenses. Gets the Company logged in.
   for(User u: this.users.values()){ //this.users has all the users on the system
       if(!u.getUserType()){ // If user is Taxpayer
           for(Expense e: c.getExpenses().values()){ //gets all the expenses of the Company.
             if(u.getTIN().equals(e.getTINUser())){ //if the user TIN is the same that the one on expense
                  t.add(e.clone());
             }
           }
       }
   }
   return t;
```

}

What I think is happening is he goes through each Taxpayer like I intend, but then it's just ordering it by value, not taking into consideration that I need to have it by each Taxpayer.

Comment: What is `f`? Why are you iterating through the same `c` company expenses each time? Your question is not clear

Comment: It was supposed to be e, fixed it already. The second question i didn't understand.

Answer (score 1):

A `Set` (`TreeSet`) is not designed to have a specific order. Rather use an ArrayList as the result of your method.

You have to do two steps:

1. Sort the expenses to the user it belong to (using a TreeMap which is sortable)
2. Iterate on the (sorted) users and extract the her expenses.

   ```
   public List<Expense> getListFactIndivValor()
   {
       Comparator<TINUser> comparator = TINUser::compareTo;
       TreeMap<TINUser, List<Expense>> map = new TreeMap<>( comparator);
       Company c = new Company();
       for ( Expense e : c.getExpenses() )
       { 
           List<Expense> expenses = map.get( e.getTINUser());
           if ( expenses == null )
           {
               expenses = new ArrayList<>();
               map.put( e.getTINUser(), expenses);
           }
           expenses.add( e);
       }

       List<Expense> result = new ArrayList<>();
       for ( TINUser u : map.descendingKeySet() )
       {
           List<Expense> expenses = map.get( u);

           for ( Expense expense : expenses )
           {
               result.add( expense);
           }
       }

       return result;
   }
   ```

Implement a compareTo() method in your TINUser class which defines the sort criteria.

Comment: The TINUser variable is in the class Expense. I need to implement the compareTo() there? Also my TINUser is just a String, should i replcae the TreeMap<TINUser, List<Expense>> for TreeMap<String, List<Expense>> ?

Comment: Yes. Since you did not provide enough details, I just guessed about yout data types. If it is a string, it is already a Comparable and you do not need to pass a comparator to the TreeMap (since it sorts according the natural order).

Comment: Actually it's still missing the part where it compares each expense. I need to sort the List<Expense> by descending value. Should i change the List<Expense> to a TreeSet<Expense> and use a comparator to sort that?

Comment: Use an ArrayList and sort it by using a comparator